# Запрос для определения идентичности полей

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица `payments_limits`, в котором есть поля `payments_id` и `payments_limits_types_id`. Когда я выполняю следующие запросы:

```
SELECT payments_id FROM payments_limits WHERE payments_limits_types_id = 1;
```

и

```
SELECT payments_id FROM payments_limits WHERE payments_limits_types_id = 2;
```

в результирующих выборках обоих запросов возвращается одинаковое количество полей.

И я хотела бы узнать, одинаковы ли эти результирующие выборки. Как это можно сделать одним запросом?

Comment: А у вас по архитектуре вообще возможно что бы payments_limits_types_id был равен двум и более значениям?

Comment: @BroouzerKing, да

Comment: то есть у вас значение payments_limits_types_id представляет собой что .. нечто вроде 1,2,3... 
или просто идут дублирования строк где в одной строке payments_limits_types_id = 1 а в другой равен 2

?

Comment: А могут быть два одинаковых payments_id для _одного_ payments_limits_types_id И если да - то учитывать ли количество при подсчете совпадения

Comment: @Mike, нет, одинаковых payment_id для одного payments_limits_types_id быть не должно

Comment: @BroouzerKing, не совсем поняла последний вопрос..

Comment: перефразируя @Mike  могут ли быть два одинаковых payments_id для двух разных payments_limits_types_id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если внутри одного набора не может быть двух одинаковых значений, то разницу в наборах можно получить следующим запросом:

```
SELECT payments_id, count(*), max(payments_limits_types_id)
  FROM payments_limits
 WHERE payments_limits_types_id IN (1, 2)
 GROUP BY payments_id
HAVING count(*)=1
```

`count(*)` должен быть равен 2 если встретилось две записи и следовательно значение есть в обоих наборах. При этом для записей которые встретились только в одном из наборов по `max(payments_limits_types_id)` можно будет понять в каком.

Если нужен только факт совпадения, можно сделать `select count(*) from (запрос_выше) A`, который даст на выходе количество расхождений

Если может быть несколько одинаковых payment_id в группе, то надо свести каждый из них до одной записи и получить количество одинаковых, а потом делать то же самое что и выше, дополнительно сверив количества (если нужно):

```
SELECT payments_id, max(cnt), min(cnt), max(payments_limits_types_id)
  FROM (
    SELECT payments_limits_types_id, payments_id, count(*) as cnt
      FROM payments_limits
     WHERE payments_limits_types_id IN (1, 2)
     GROUP BY payments_limits_types_id, payments_id
  ) A
 GROUP BY payments_id
HAVING count(*)=1 OR min(cnt)<>max(cnt)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно ещё вариант, если у одного payments_limits_types_id может быть несколько одинаковых payment_id?

Comment: @Ksenia Дополнил