# SQL выборка по повторяющимся значениям

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Как составить SQL запрос для выборки значений поля «Имя 1», у которых все пары «Параметр» + «Значение» равны парам «Параметр» + «Значение» из второй таблицы.

Например первая таблица:

```
+--------------------------------------+     
| ID   Имя 1      Параметр   Значение  |
| 1    Товар 1    Длина      50        |
| 2    Товар 1    Ширина     100       |
| 3    Товар 2    Длина      80        |
| 4    Товар 2    Ширина     100       |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Вторая таблица

```
+----------------------------------------+     
| ID   Имя 2        Параметр   Значение  |
| 1    Продукт 1    Длина      50        |
| 2    Продукт 1    Ширина     100       |
| 3    Продукт 2    Длина      25        |
| 4    Продукт 2    Ширина     100       |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Таким образом, товару 1 соответствует продукт 1. И искомый запрос бы вывел «Товар 1»

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568826/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/568840#568840

Comment: Не очень понимаю, как это можно применить тут. Не могли бы объяснить логику применения примера на данную задачу?

Comment: А вы для начала скажите как связать эти две таблицы. Я в них вижу идентичными только параметр-значение. Как понять какие строки второй таблицы надо рассматривать для товара 1, какие для товара 2. Что если во второй таблице будет еще продукт 3 и то же с длиной 50 и шириной 100. Получится уже два продукта совпадающие по параметрам с товаром 1

Comment: Связать их только по совпадению всех «параметров».
То есть у каждого «товара» может быть несколько «параметров» и нужно вывести все «продукты», которые совпадают по всем «параметрам». 
То есть если будет  «продукт 3»  с длиной «50» и шириной «100», его тоже надо вывести

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подразумеваем, что имена параметров не повторяются внутри одного товара или продукта!

**Вариант1.** Если количество возможных параметров товара известно заранее (в вашем примере два), то можно так:

```
SELECT t1.name1, t2.name2, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM 
    table1 AS t1 JOIN
    table2 AS t2 ON (t1.attr, t1.val) = (t2.attr, t2.val)
GROUP BY name1, name2
HAVING cnt = 2
```

См. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4136/6
Здесь мы находим совпадения параметр-значение между товарами и продуктами. Группируем чтобы посчитать количество совпадений и фильтруем по этому количеству.

**Вариант 2.** Количество параметров произвольное и надо найти такие товары, для которых все описанные у товара параметры, сколько бы их ни было, находятся у какого-то продукта.

```
SELECT g1.*
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.name1, t2.name2, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM 
        table1 AS t1 JOIN
        table2 AS t2 ON (t1.attr, t1.val) = (t2.attr, t2.val)
    GROUP BY name1, name2
) AS g1 JOIN
(
    SELECT name1, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY name1
) AS g2 ON (g1.name1, g1.CNT) = (g2.name1, g2.CNT)
```

См. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4136/7
Понадобился второй группирующий запрос чтобы посчитать нужное число параметров.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM (
      SELECT table1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(table1.param, table1.value) ORDER BY table1.param ASC) params
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY table1.id
     ) t1,
     (
      SELECT table2.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(table2.param, table2.value) ORDER BY table2.param ASC) params
      FROM table2
      GROUP BY table2.id
     ) t2
WHERE t1.params = t2.params;
```

Comment: PS. От дубликатов записей страховка есть, а вот от мультизначений - нет. Если они встречаются, то в ORDER BY тоже нужно вместо одного поля конкатенацию поставить.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select A.a_name, A.b_name
   from (
         select A.name as a_name, B.name as b_name, count(1) as cnt
           from Tab1 A, Tab2 B
          where B.parm=A.parm and B.val=A.val
          group by A.name, B.name
        ) A
   join (select name, count(1) as cnt from Tab1 group by name) AC on AC.name=A.a_name
   join (select name, count(1) as cnt from Tab2 group by name) BC on BC.name=A.b_name
  where A.cnt=AC.cnt and AC.cnt=BC.cnt
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, запрос требует чтобы число параметров у товара и продукта было одинаково. Но скорее всего, достаточно AC.cnt<=BC.cnt Переложил на свои имена столбцов: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4136/21

Comment: @artoodetoo Значит ТС не верно описал задачу. Я по его постановке рассчитывал на поиск полного совпадения вне зависимости от количества параметров.

Comment: Я настолько не уточнял задачу, по условию верны и тот, и другой запрос. Спасибо!